# How to add a line between every two rows in a spread sheet?

Tags: spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I was wondering in Openoffice Calc spreadsheet, how to add a line between every two rows? I want to print a spreadsheet, with a line separating every two rows.
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find it easier with both Calc and Excel to select the rows, right-click -> Row height and then enter double the current row height.

If you *really* want a blank row between each:

- add a column
- Put numbers 1, 2,  ..., n for each of your rows
- Put 1.5, 2.5, ..., n+.5 in each of the blank rows following row n
- Sort by that column (this will "Faro shuffle" your original and blank rows)
- delete that column

Doesn't the first option sound a lot better?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column. Select the cells in the new column for the desired rows. `edit/fill/series` (start with "1") and press enter. Select an equal number of cells in the new column below the desired rows. `edit/fill/series` (start with "1.5"). Select all cells. `data/sort/column` "A". Delete the new column.